# How to search across multiple fields in Lucene using Query Syntax?

Tags: java, lucene, indexing

I'm searching a lucene index and I'm building search queries like

```
field1:"hello" AND field2:"world"
```

but I'd like to search for a value in any field as well as the values in specific fields in the same query i.e.

```
field1:"hello" AND anyField:"world"
```

Can anyone tell me how I can search across all indexed fields in this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the answers I got for this question: [Impact of repeat value across multiple fields in Lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356837/impact-of-repeat-value-across-multiple-fields-in-lucene)...

I can put the same search term into multiple fields and therefore create an "all" field which I put everything in. This way I can create a query like...

```
field1:"hello" AND all:"world"
```

This seems to work very nicely, prevents the need for huge search queries, and apparently the performance impact is minimal.

Answer (score 2):

Boolean (OR) queries with a clause for each field are used to search multiple fields.  The [MultiFieldQueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/MultiFieldQueryParser.html) will do that as well, but the fields still need to be enumerated.  There's no implicit "all" fields;  but [IndexReader.getFieldNames](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#getFieldNames%28org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.FieldOption%29) can acquire them.

Comment: I've created an explicit "all" field... it doesn't seem ideal but every time I create a field I also add to the "all" field. It works but seems a bit rubbish. Really what I'd like to do is define multiple names for each indexed field so I can create categories or be able to search fields using wildcard characters in the field names so I could search "name*" for "name.firstname:bob"

Answer (score 0):

This might not apply to you, but in Azure Search, which is based on Lucene, using Lucene syntax, I use this:

```
name:plywood^100 OR plywood
```

Results with "plywood" in the "name" field are boosted.